# Excel help - Move through a list until condition is satisfied

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a small section of a spreadsheet less manual, to then avoid duplication of a piece of work and reduce the possibility of errors in moving/copying info from one place to another.

I have a number of staff titles, at varying amounts of hours in a summary, based on which I want to populate another table. I want one row per employee, based on a 40 hour week. So in the below screenshot, there would be one row for a manager, and 2 rows for supervisors, with the first one showing one full time staff member (40h), and the next row showing 0.5 of a full time employee (20h). It is the staff title, and hours/WTE I am trying to populate info for. I know if I get the staff hours to pull correctly, the WTE can work from there, or vice versa.

I have filled in the info presenting the desired outcome, and I have tried a couple of different ways but haven't managed to find one that then allows it to move on to the next row based on what happened in the row above.

[image: two tables screenshot]

Essentially I can't even get past the point that I have a formula that acknowledges the first staff title has been fulfilled and is all input in the table, and then moves on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cleaner with Excel O365, and this will not be a flexible/dynamic solution.  But...

Assume this table:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager | 40 |
| 2 | Supervisor | 60 |
| 3 | Assistant | 175 |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 | Manager |  |
| 6 | Supervisor |  |
| 7 | Supervisor |  |
| 8 | Assistant |  |
| 9 | Assistant |  |
| 10 | Assistant |  |
| 11 | Assistant |  |
| 12 | Assistant |  |

In B5 you could put this formula and copy it down:

`=MIN(40, VLOOKUP(A5,$A$1:$B$3,2,0)-SUMIF(A4:A$4,A5,B4:B$4))`

This looks up the number of hours needed, subtracts the the number of hour already accounted for in previous rows, and displays that remaining balance, or if there's still more than 40 hours to be accounted for, displays 40.

This assumes that row 4 can be left blank, or that A4 does not have a matching title to A5.  If not, you have to check for a first instance to avoid a circular reference by doing something like:

`=IF(A4=A5,MIN(40, VLOOKUP(A5,$A$1:$B$3,2,0)-SUMIF(A4:A$5,A5,B4:B$5)),MIN(40, VLOOKUP(A5,$A$1:$B$3,2,0)))`

It's a bit more cumbersome, so leaving row 4 blank is easier.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic implementation of the problem could work as follows in Office365:

Assuming that the titles are written in the cells `B2:B4`, and the hours are written in cells `C2:C4`, also illustrated here:

[image: data screenshot]

then the desired table can be dynamically generated with the formula...

1. for the list of titles:

```
=LET(
    hours,$C$2:$C$4,
    titles,$B$2:$B$4,
    title_index,ROUNDUP(hours/40,0),
    title_roll,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,3,1,0),(SEQUENCE(3)<=SEQUENCE(1,3))*(title_index)),
    staff_count,SEQUENCE(SUM(title_index)),
    criterium_a,N(staff_count>title_roll),
    title_seq,MMULT(criterium_a,SEQUENCE(3,1,1,0))+1,
    INDEX(titles,title_seq)
)
```

2. for the list of hour/wte

```
=LET(
    hours,$C$2:$C$4,
    title_index,ROUNDUP(hours/40,0),
    title_roll,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,3,1,0),(SEQUENCE(3)<=SEQUENCE(1,3))*(title_index)),
    staff_count,SEQUENCE(SUM(title_index)),
    criterium_a,N(staff_count>title_roll),
    title_seq,MMULT(criterium_a,SEQUENCE(3,1,1,0))+1,
    wte_dist,INDEX(hours/40,title_seq)-TRANSPOSE(staff_count-1),
    hour_tabl,((wte_dist>=1)+(wte_dist<1)*(wte_dist>0)*(wte_dist))*40,
    criterium_b,N((title_seq>TRANSPOSE(title_seq))<>(staff_count>TRANSPOSE(staff_count))),
    hour_col,MMULT(criterium_b,staff_count^0)+1,
    INDEX(hour_tabl,staff_count,hour_col)
)
```

which then looks as shown here below

[image: result screenshot]